# Computing binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Compute from Left-Side: 
$$ {n \choose p} {n-p \choose k-p} = {n \choose k-p \quad p  \quad n-k } = {n \choose k} {k \choose p}$$

So i started computing until:

$$ ={n \choose p} {n-p \choose k-p}$$
$$=\left(\frac{(n!)}{(p!) (n-p)!}\right) \left(\frac{(n-p)!}{(k-p)! ((n-p)-(k-p))!}\right) $$
$$=\left(\frac{(n!)}{(p!) (n-p)!}\right) \left(\frac{(n-p)!}{(k-p)! (n-k)!}\right) $$

and this is where i get stuck.  How can i continue breaking this down until it equals the right-side? What algebraic definitions or binomial theorems am i not understanding? help?

Comment: Cancel out the $(n-p)!$. Then expand the right side in a similar way and simplify. You will see that they are equal.

Comment: wow I'm so blind! I swear.

Comment: It happens. Can you think of a combinatorial argument for this equality?

Comment: umm nothing comes to mind. But tell me?

Comment: Suppose you have $n$ senators and want to create a committee of size $k$, and then in this committee a sub-commitee of size $p$. The sides of the equality count the number of ways you can do this in two different ways, so they are equal.

Comment: Good way to put it! +1 thanks.

Comment: Is there a typo in your third binomial coefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have $$\frac{n!}{p!\color{red}{(n-p)!}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{(n-p)!}}{(k-p)!((n-p)-(k-p))!}=\frac{n!}{p!(k-p)!(n-k)!}.$$
Now, mutiplying this by $\frac{k!}{k!}\ (=1)$ gives
$$\frac{n!}{p!(k-p)!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{k!}{k!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{k!}{p!(k-p)!}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{p}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel out $(n-p)!$

$\left(\frac{(n!)}{(p!) (n-p)!}\right) \left(\frac{(n-p)!}{(k-p)! (n-k)!}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{(n!)}{(p!) }\right) \left(\frac{1}{(k-p)! (n-k)!}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{(n!)}{(p!)(k-p)! (n-k)!}\right)$

$ = {n \choose k-p \quad p  \quad n-k }$

And

$\left(\frac{(n!)}{(p!)(k-p)! (n-k)!}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{(n!)}{(k!) (n-k)!}\right) \left(\frac{(k!)}{(p!)(k-p)!}\right)$

$ = {n \choose k} {k \choose p}$

Answer (score 1):

Using the "subset of a subset" identity 
$$\binom ab\binom bc=\binom ac\binom {a-c}{b-c}$$
(which can be proven by expansion but also makes sense logically) and putting $a=n, b=k,c=p$,we have
$$\begin{align}
\text{RHS}&=\binom nk\binom kp\\
&=\binom np\binom {n-p}{k-p}=\text{LHS}\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$